# How to reInitialized view when going into another class kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im getting this error

```
     kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized,
```

and i wonder if its possible to reInitialized my recyclerview when i go from another class then back to the view again?.

Comment: An instance of a class can only be initialized once. When you return to an Activity or Fragment, it's possible a new one is instantiated. So long as you are initializing your `lateinit` properties in `create()`, you won't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that you have use `lateinit` property and didn't initialize it.Do initialize it in `onCreate()` method.Checkout this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables